# Can I juxtapose two clauses that share one object?

Tags: clauses, objects

To make the sentence short, I am putting two clauses side by side that share one object. The sentence I wanted to say is:

> Meltwater of the glaciers, especially outbursts of glacier-dammed
>   lakes and moraine-dammed lakes, provide deluges of water, and glacial
>   outwash provides abundant loose material, for debris flows.

Is it Okay to write like this?

Comment: Well yes. But it also achieves the exact opposite of what you're after. By taking two short sentences and merging them into a single long sentence, you're not making the sentence short. You're making it twice the length it needs to be.

Comment: No; it may be grammatical, but violates the Gricean maxim of manner. It could be put a lot more clearly.

Comment: Thank you guys for the answer and the comments. I learnt a lot. I will put the sentence into two sentences to make it clear and easy to read.

Answer (score 1):

Your sentence was:

1. Meltwater of the glaciers, especially outbursts of glacier-dammed lakes
   and moraine-dammed lakes, provide deluges of water, and glacial outwash
   provides abundant loose material, for debris flows.

You need to isolate each heavy syntactic element and then think of
alternate ways of expressing the same idea that make the syntax of such a
long sentence easier on your reader. This is a word-salad whose syntax is
dubious and confusing at best:

```
C1: (meltwater (of the glaciers))
    (especially outbursts of (glacier-dammed lakes and moraine-dammed lakes))
    (provides)
    (deluges of water)

and

C2:  (glacial outwash)
     (provides)
     (abundant loose material)

Adj: (for (debris flows))
```

You don't want "C1 and C2 for debris flows", because that doesn't make sound grammatical
sense, and also because *loose material for debris flows* is a
garden-path collocation that leads your reader to misparse your sentence.

Trimming the extra bits, the key elements of your sentence work out to:

2. Meltwater *provide deluges and outwash provides loose material for debris flows.

The first verb *provide* is in the wrong number because its subject is
*meltwater*.  The verb should therefore be the singular *provides*, but
that's the least of your troubles.

Your sentence contains neither a compound verb nor a compound subject, and
making your two clauses sharing the same adjunct is a different kettle of
fish.

#### Clause One

- subject: *meltwater*
- verb: *provides*
- object: *deluges*

#### Clause Two

- subject: *outwash*
- verb: *provides*
- object: *material*

The only thing those two independent clauses share in common is their verb,
but it has not been reduced as you would with a compound subject.  That's
because the first subject goes with the first object, and the second
subject goes with the second object.

The syntactic element you are trying to make apply to both those two
clauses is the adjunct *for debris flows*. That is not the direct
object. If you move the shared element to the start of the sentence,
this becomes clearer:

3. For debris flow, meltwater provides deluges and outwash provides material.

Stylistically it is possible — but not always expedient — to factor out the
second verb:

4. For debris flow, meltwater provides the deluges and outwash the material.

This sort of thing only works when the elements are light (short) the way I've
outlined them here. Longer, heavier elements will lose the reader.

If we start putting back your extra element, the reader becomes lost. But
we should fix what you have there first. Your parenthetical

- especially outbursts of glacier-dammed lakes and moraine-dammed lakes,

should be reduced because the duplication is too plodding. You have
two choices, of which I prefer the second.

- especially outbursts of glacier- and moraine-dammed lakes,
- especially outbursts of lakes dammed by glaciers and moraines,

I also think those should be *from* not *of*:

- especially outbursts from lakes dammed by glaciers and moraines,

Be careful when adding back the material I've omitted in the previous
focused solutions lest your reader become lost or bored.  Your sentence as
originally written is much too complicated to hold the reader's attention.  Many
readers will lose track of just exactly what's doing what to
what, and to what purpose.

Try switching around the order of these individual constituents. Consider
using nonfinite clauses via participles or infinitives to enliven the
structure so your reader doesn't get bored with repetitive grammatical
constructions.  There's more than one way to skin a cat; here follow only a
few of many possible ways:

6. Glacial meltwater, especially when released suddenly in outbursts from
   lakes dammed by glaciers and moraines, combines with the loose material
   from glacial outwash to provide for debris flows.
7. Glacial meltwater, particularly meltwater released in a sudden outburst
   from lakes whose glacial or moraine dams fail, combines with loose material
   from glacial outwash to provide debris flows.
8. Glacial meltwater, particularly meltwater released in a sudden outburst
   from lakes whose glacial or moraine dams fail, combines with loose material
   from glacial outwash to create debris flows.
9. Debris flows are provided for by glacial meltwater, especially if released
   suddenly from lakes previously dammed by glaciers and moraines, combining
   with the loose material of glacial outwash.
10. Debris flows are created when glacial meltwater, especially if released
    as a sudden outburst from lakes previously dammed by glaciers and moraines,
    combines with loose material from glacial outwash.

But seriously consider using more than one sentence: the use of a full stop
(aka a period) should not be considered a moral failure by the writer. Rather,
think of it as a kindness towards the reader.